# Records as parameters, composition

Tags: scala, shapeless

EDIT: I reformulate the question to something simpler and less domain specific:
In the following code, I'd like to implement the mplus function that combines two functions constrained by the presence of a specific field. The resulting function should be constrained by the presence of the two fields. 
Thanks !

```
import shapeless._, ops.record.Selector, record._, syntax.singleton._

def requiresIntervalKey[L <: HList](l: L)
                                   (implicit sel: Selector.Aux[L, Witness.`"interval"`.T, Int]): Unit = {
  println(sel(l))
}
def requiresPlatformField[L <: HList](l: L)
                                     (implicit sel: Selector.Aux[L, Witness.`"platform"`.T, String]): Unit = {
  println(sel(l))
}
def mplus = ??? // That is the function I'd like to implement. Eventually it will be the additive operator of a monoid

// needsBothFields: L <: HList -> (implicit) Selector.Aux[L, Witness.`"interval"`.T, Int] -> (implicit) Selector.Aux[L, Witness.`"platform"`.T, String] -> Unit
val needsBothField = mplus(requiresIntervalKey _, requiresIntervalKey _ )

// Usage
requiresIntervalKey(("interval" ->> "a string") :: HNil) // Shoudn't compile, value type is wrong
requiresIntervalKey(("wrongKey" ->> "a string") :: HNil) // Shoudn't compile, "interval" key not provided
requiresIntervalKey(("interval" ->> 42) :: HNil) // Compiles
requiresPlatformField(("platform" ->> "EU") :: HNil) // Compiles
needsBothFields(("interval" ->> 42) :: ("platform" ->> "EU") :: HNil) // Should compile
```

// Previous question version

Quite new to shapeless and typelevel programming, I am struggling to achieve my objective and get a clear understanding. Your help would be very appreciated!

I basically have several functions looking like the following :

```
trait PathGenerator[T] {
  def apply(T): Set[Seq[String]]
}

val hourlyIntervalPathGenerator: PathGenerator[Interval] = ???
val constantGenerator: PathGenerator[String] = ???

// A Monoid[PathGenerator]
// an implicit class adding a '/' operator to PathGenerator

// Usage
val hourlyRegionPathGenerator = hourlyIntervalPathGenerator / constantGenerator
val paths = hourlyRegionPathGenerator(StaticIntervals.lastDay, "EU")
```

Now when adding more than two generators together, user has to juggle with nested tuples. Furthermore, naming the generators parameters would be very useful for generating a parser (ex: cmd-line.)

Shapeless records seem to be a great fit, so I went on and implemented the following non-working solution: 
https://gist.github.com/amazari/911449b55270a5871d14

Several issues arise from this non-buildable code and my shapeless misunderstanding:

- getting the value of a field from a record (`L26: keys("interval")` and `L35: keys(constant)`) doesn't return a value of the expected type, even tough a Witness and a selector are provided.
- I can't get to extract the right sub-record types to pass to underlying generators when composing two of them (L52-53.)
- L69: somehow the provided record do not match the required type for reason I don't understand.

So, are records the right tool to achieve this use case? Not shown in the snippet is a command-line parser generated from the record shape/template of a PathPattern.

How could I enforce that the record provided to a generator (simple or resulting from the combination of several) has exactly the right fields in term of names and types?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: This series of questions and Travis Brown's answers are very relevant:

[Passing a Shapeless Extensible Record to a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308143/passing-a-shapeless-extensible-record-to-a-function)
[Passing a Shapeless Extensible Record to a Function (continued)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311599/passing-a-shapeless-extensible-record-to-a-function-continued)
[Passing a shapeless extensible record to a function (never ending story?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693661/passing-a-shapeless-extensible-record-to-a-function-never-ending-story)

Comment: I'll try to look at this in more detail later today, but one quick note: any time you have something statically typed as an `HList`, it's likely something's wrong. You'll often have things that are constrained to be subtypes of `HList`, but you need static information about _what_ subtype—there's almost nothing you can do with a plain old `HList`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I tried to distill the sample code to something more digestible. See the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *kind of* possible with Shapeless, although not in exactly the form you're asking for. Here's a quick example:

```
import shapeless._, ops.record.Selector, record._, syntax.singleton._

class UseKey[K <: String, V, R](w: Witness.Aux[K])(f: V => R) extends Poly1 {
  implicit def onRecord[L <: HList](implicit
    sel: Selector.Aux[L, K, V]
  ): Case.Aux[L, R] = at[L](l => f(sel(l)))
}

class Combine[P1 <: Poly1, P2 <: Poly1, R1, R2, R](
  p1: P1,
  p2: P2
)(f: (R1, R2) => R) extends Poly1 {
  implicit def onRecord[L <: HList](implicit
    c1: p1.Case.Aux[L, R1],
    c2: p2.Case.Aux[L, R2]
  ): Case.Aux[L, Unit] = at[L](l => f(c1(l), c2(l)))
}

class mplus[P1 <: Poly1, P2 <: Poly1](p1: P1, p2: P2)
  extends Combine(p1, p2)((_: Unit, _: Unit) => ())
```

And then:

```
object requiresIntervalKey extends UseKey(Witness("interval"))(
  (i: Int) => println(i)
)

object requiresPlatformField extends UseKey(Witness("platform"))(
  (s: String) => println(s)
)

object needsBothFields extends mplus(requiresIntervalKey, requiresPlatformField)
```

(As a side note, I would have guessed that you could just write `UseKey("platform")` here, but for some reason the implicit conversion that captures the witness doesn't work. Fortunately `Witness("platform")` isn't too bad.)

And next to show it works:

```
scala> import test.illTyped
import test.illTyped

scala> illTyped("""requiresIntervalKey("interval" ->> "a string" :: HNil)""")

scala> illTyped("""requiresIntervalKey("wrongKey" ->> "a string" :: HNil)""")

scala> requiresIntervalKey("interval" ->> 42 :: HNil)
42

scala> requiresPlatformField("platform" ->> "EU" :: HNil)
EU

scala> needsBothFields("interval" ->> 42 :: "platform" ->> "EU" :: HNil)
42
EU
```

The reason we need `Poly1` instead of regular old functions is that we can't collect the different pieces of evidence we need when combining ordinary functions—instead we need polymorphic function values (which Shapeless provides as `PolyN`).

It's also worth noting that this isn't really a "monoid". A monoid instance for a type provides an operation that takes two values of that type and returns another. The `mplus` here takes two operations, each of which has its own implicit requirements, and gives us another operation which has the combined requirements of both.